# How do I make a generic @OneToMany mapping of concrete classes using their super type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a base abstract class defined like so :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class State implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(name = "stateCode")
private String code;
}
```

The concrete classes such as `StateA`, `StateB`... `StateZ` were defined like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stateA")
public class StateA extends State implements serializable{

}
```

There's also a `Region` class like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "region")
public class Region {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = " regionCode")
private String regionCode;

}
```

Each of the concrete `State` classes references the `Region` class in the database.
However, I'm struggling to have a `OneToMany` mapping like this in the Region class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "region", cascade= cascadeType.ALL)
private Set<State> state = new HashSet<>()
```

And the following `ManyToOne` mapping in the abstract `State` class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "regionId")
private Region region;
```

but it wouldn't work since `State` is an unmapped entity. Is there a way I can make a generic mapping of concrete `State` in the `Region` class without having to declare each of the concrete classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "region", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<State> state = new HashSet<>();
```

You could not use @OneToMany association to List
of State class cause it's not Entity. You should use a collection of entities that inherits from State class.

I think your code will be fine if you change the code above into that one:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "region", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<StateA> state = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change inheritance strategy, I recommend you to use single table strategy, so in my opinion you  you should  transform your   'State' class to this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class State implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "stateCode")
    private String code;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "regionId")
    private Region region;
}
```

Comment: I had really wished to not change the Inheritance strategy. I thought there was a way I could do this using my preferred strategy.